# Cannot access basic functionality Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox on a Windows host. Unity doesn't load completely when I login. I am not able to access the Launcher nor am I able to open the terminal. All that I am able to do is open the file explorer, but that too does not show the menu bar. The system looks something like this.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the VBoxGuestAdditions by going to Devices (while the VM is running) and selecting "Install Guest Additions..." and then installing as if this was from a disk.
This seems to be the answer to most graphical issues in VBox.